# JQuery Autocomplete with ASp.Net webservice

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am working on the JQuery Autocomplete using ASP.Net webservice.
I have ASP.Net webservice being called in JQuery (JSON) drop down as

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtTest").autocomplete({ 
         source: function (request, response) {  
             $.ajax({  
                 type: "POST",  
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                 url: "Webservice.asmx/GetNames",
                 data: "{'prefix':'" + request.term + "'}",  
                 dataType: "json",  
                 async: true,  
                 success: function (data){  
                    response($.map(data, function(item)
                    { return item ; }));  
                },  
                error: function (result) {  
                   alert("Due to unexpected errors we were unable to load data");  
                }  
             });
         },  
         minLength:2
     });
 });
```

And i am getting the output on the drop of auto-complete as

```
 {"First":"Steve","Second":"AK"}
 {"First":"Evet","Second":"EV"}
 {"First":"Stevens","Second":"SV"}
```

How do i display the "First" items alone (Like Steve, Evet, Stevens) as the output of the drop down auto-complete?

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the formatItem option on the AutoComplete method - try this

```
formatItem: function(row, i, n) {
      return row.First;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

this would probably do the trick

```
   success: function (data)
    {  
        response($.map(data, function (item)
         {
             return { label: item.First, value: item.First}
         }))
    });
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. But your trick is not helping me. Could you please revisit your snippet? I am not getting any values. Please help me.

Comment: do you get an error? is there somewhere were we can see the application running?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my answer to this one:  [Jquery Autocomplete 2 Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740234/jquery-autocomplete-2-fields/7741857#7741857)

but use your values instead of "A" and "B" in the fields.

In addition, you (might) need a converter to handle the asp.net data:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Webservice.asmx/GetNames",
    dataType: "jsond",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    converters: {
        "json jsond": function(msg)
        {
            return msg.hasOwnProperty('d') ? msg.d : msg;
        }
    },
...
```