# Jquery Autocomplete 2 Fields

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-autocomplete

I have the following page :

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style type='text/css'>

    .ui-menu-item   {

        font-size:50%;

    }

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $("#a").autocomplete({

            source: "query.php",
            minLength: 2

        });

    });

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <form action="todo.php"  method="post">

    A <input type='text' name='a' id='a'><br/>
    B <input type='text' name='b' id='b'><br/>

    </form>

</body>

 </html>
```

The `query.php` that returns `JSON data`

```
include("connect.inc.php");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT a, b FROM table WHERE a LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term'])."%' ORDER BY a ASC LIMIT 0,10") or die(mysql_error());

$data = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    $data[] = $row['a'];

}
   include("close.inc.php");
   echo json_encode($data);
```

The Database contains 2 rows, obviously a and b.

The question is : how can I alter the current script in order to autocomplete both a and b where a corresponds to b in the mysql database

I tried to figure it out but I couldn't wrap my head around it (for about a week or so).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you explain more what do you want to do? And what is your problem exactly?

Comment: i want to autocomplete <input type='text' name='b'> based on the value of 'a' , given you have a table with 2 collumns, a and b.

Comment: you will type in input "a" , and you want to autocomplete input "b". am i right ? can you share your JSON data which return by query.php ?

Comment: sure : [["asd1","b1"],["asd2","b1"],["asf1","b2"]] // asd1, asd2 and asf1 would represent some names or products, b1 and b2 are categories or regions or groups, and yeah, if i type data into a, i'd like b to be autocompleted based on the data inside the table

Comment: so, when you type asd1 to a, b will display b1 or asf1 to a, b will display b2 ?

Comment: yeah, in my example table : asd1 = b1, asd2 = b1, asf1 = b2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think you would want your JSON to be of the form `[{"a":"asd1","b":"b1"},{"a":"asd2","b":"b1"}...]` then you could process it using a parse function like so:

```
function myAutocompleteJSONParse(data)
{
    var rows = new Array();
    var rowData = null;
    for (var i = 0, dataLength = data.length; i < dataLength; i++)
    {
        rowData = data[i];
        rows[i] = {
            value: rowData.A,
            label: rowData.A,
            A: rowData.A,
            B: rowData.B
        };
    }
    return rows;
};
```

You could then call this from the ajax so:

```
...
    success: function(data)
    {
        if (!data || data.length == 0)
        {
            var rows = new Array();
            rows[0] = { A: 'Not Found',
                B: ''
            };

            response(rows);
        }
        else
        {
            var rows = myAutocompleteJSONParse(data);
            response(rows);
        }
    }
...
```

then in the autocomplete handle it in the select:

```
...
select: function(event, ui)
{
    var hasValue = (ui.item.value != undefined && ui.item.value != "" && ui.item.value != null);
    if (hasValue)
    {
        var focusedElement = $(this);
        focusedElement.val(ui.item.label);
        $("#b").val(ui.item.B);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
},
...
```

Assumptions here: using the jQuery UI Autocomplete, using current jQuery 1.6.4 version